# Classification using regression coefficients

Tags: logistic, classification, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients

While circumventing logistic regression, is there a way to binary classify new observations based on learned linear regression coefficients?

*Clarification*:

Suppose a variable of interest $A$ is assumed to be linearly dependent of $n$ variables $X = (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, i.e.
\begin{align}
A &= \alpha_1 X_1 + \alpha_2 X_2 + \ldots + \alpha_n X_n + \epsilon,
\end{align}
where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. All observations of $A$ belong either to class $-1$ or $1$, i.e. $A = A^{-1} \cup A^1$. For observed data, two sets of parameters $\mathcal{D}^{-1}$ and $\mathcal{D}^{1}$ are learnt based on ordinary least squares (OLS), i.e. 
\begin{align}
A^{-1} &= \mathcal{D}^{-1} X + \epsilon \\
A^{1} &= \mathcal{D}^{1} X + \epsilon.
\end{align}
As new data becomes available, both $A^*$ *and* $X^*$, I am wondering whether $D^*$ (such that
$A^* = \mathcal{D}^* X^* + \eta, \text{ where } \eta \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$) can be used to assign $A^*$ to class $-1$ or $1$?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a group variable and an interaction between your current variables and the group variable. Then you would fit that model to predict $A =A^1\cup A^{-1}$. But what exactly are you trying to do? If you want to classify, why not use logistic regression (or some other classification technique like SVM or a neural network)?

Comment: SVM and neural networks are not an option since I want to do causal modeling, i.e. interpretation of the coefficients. The main reason to avoid logistic regression is that $A$ is part of a mediation model*, i.e. $X \rightarrow \mathcal{D} \rightarrow A$.

* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_(statistics)

Comment: So is $A$ a collection of values with some threshold, like $<120$ is low blood pressure and $>120$ is high blood pressure? (Nobody should take this comment as medical advice.)

Comment: $A$ is the response time, i.e. $t \geq 0$. $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are variables I want to interpret whether they influence $A$, and $A^{1}$ resp. $A^{-1}$  indicates if a customer bought an article (or not).

Comment: just as a rough sketch: If your predictions are produced by OLS models you have implicitly assumed the responses $A$ to follow normal distributions (I will continue to omit the asterisks, also in the following). In other words, you may from that compute the class conditional distributions $p(A|D^1,X)$ and $p(A|D^{-1},X)$. Together with the class priors $p(D^i)$ (which you can get simply from the sample share of each class) and Bayes rule this should allow you to compute the posteriors $p(D^i|A)$, which can be directly used for class assignment